# Generating items and using srand

Tags: c++, random

I am creating a game and I am currently working on the random drop system.

I plan on creating a random ID which in turn is a design for the items. If I pass the same ID twice to the createItem function it should create the exact same item.

Anyway. When I create the ID I plan on using input to be able to let some enemies drop a certain item more often. So lets say that the function looks like this for example:

```
void randID(int level, int diff, float wepChance, float armChance);
```

If I set the wepChance to 10% (0.1) when I call the function I really want it to be a 10% chance of dropping a weapon. How do I use this input together with a `rand()` and `srand()`? How does srand really work (haven't found anything else than that is creates a seed).

I guess I could write my own code to make it really become 10% chance, but can I use srand to achieve the same result?

Comment: `srand` is really not the answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`srand` will not help you with this.

If you want a 10% chance of something occurring, then use something like the following:

```
int x = rand();

bool hasOccurred = (x < (RAND_MAX * 0.1));
```

This won't be *exactly* 10%, because `RAND_MAX` probably doesn't divide exactly by 10, but I imagine it's close enough for your application.

Comment: Yeah, thanks i guess i might have to go that route to create that. Thanks for a quick reply!

Comment: Is there any reason to use srand before this? srand wouldn't make a difference right?

Comment: @Tallkotten: Generally speaking, you call `srand` **once** at the beginning of your entire program.

Answer (score 0):

srand and rand are 'pseudorandom number generator'.
srand means 'seed random' and is usually used with 'time(NULL);'

```
srand(time(NULL)); //Guarantees, that you won't get the exact same row of numbers twice.
rand()%100;        //For example.
```

Regarding that input problem of yours: It's like rolling a dice.
Let's say you assume numbers from 0-99 (%100), you say 'ItemID 1' for results < 10.
In this context, that means a chance of 10 %.

rand is not the most reliable random number generator and should not be used for cryptographic issues (since the rows are mathematically predictable), but for games it should work just fine.

Does that help?

Ah yes, speaking in code.

```
srand(time(NULL));         //Initializes the random number generator. (Call once)
randID(1, 5, 0.1, 0.2);    //Assuming some parameters here

void randID(int level, int diff, float wepChance, float armChance) {        
    int Rand = rand()%100;
    wepChance *= 100;    //Maximum dice roll for a weapon
    armChance = wepChance + (armChance * 100); //Maximum dice roll for an arm.
    if(Rand <= wepChance) //doWeapon
    else if(Rand > WepChance && Rand < armChance) //doArm
}
```

This is untested and rather crude code, but I think you know what I'm getting at.
After all, I don't quite know exactly what you mean to do.

Comment: You should add a note that it's not a good idea to call `srand` too often. If the time hasn't changed between calls to `srand`, subsequent `rand` calls will return the same value.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you for this information. Actually I kinda suggested that in my edit just now. But really, thanks for the head's up.